Lenovo Yoga Duet 7-13IML05 keyboard in ubuntu not working
[Background] Lenovo Yoga Duet 7-13IML05 keyboard is detachable. the keyboard has two modes:

directly plug (Magnetic attraction)
detach mode (Bluetooth connect)

[Issue] After install the ubuntu2404 desktop version, directly plug mode not functioning. The detach mode (Bluetooth connect) works fine.
[Question] if there any drive can work with the Lenovo Yoga Duet 7-13IML05 keyboard (Direct plug mode)?
[Reference] I read this web it shows can works in arch Linux https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_Yoga_Duet_7_13IML05
Computer details: https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/tw/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/yoga-series/yoga-duet-7-13iml05
[Remark] but I tried to install "iio-sensor-proxy package" not work in ubuntu 2404.
can I seek for any helps?
thanks.
